# "To be + V3" or not?

Tags: passive-voice

I read instruction on battery replacement and encountered sentence:
"if unit is to be disposed for long time, make sure to take out the batteries."
I don't underestand why it is used here construction "to be + V3", because, to my mind, it would be right to write
"if unit is disposed for long time, make sure to take out the batteries."
Tell me, please, where I am wrong.

Comment: The instructions have at least one error: "to be disposed" means *discarded*, when obviously what is intended is, "to be stored." That said, the grammar is correct as-is.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik There are other issues, too: the lack of determiners for "unit" and "long time". This reads like headlinese, which may be OK in this context but is certainly not how people usually speak or write.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan, agreed - but even as "headlinese", *dispose* is an error in *sense*, as opposed to grammar. Is no articles in some languages;-)